# Application crashes when accessing .content of StyleSheet

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I have the following React Native component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class ListItem extends React.Component {

render() {
    return (
        <View style={itemStyle.content}>
            <Image
              style={imageStyle.content}
              source={this.props.someSource}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
}


var imageStyle = StyleSheet.create({
    content:{
        flexDirection:'column',
        alignItems:'center',
        alignSelf: 'flex-end',
        justifyContent:'center',
        backgroundColor: '#7CFC00',//light green
        width: '95%',
        height: '80%',
        resizeMode: 'contain',
        marginRight: '14%'
    }
});


var itemStyle = StyleSheet.create({
  content:{
    flexDirection:'row',
    alignItems:'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    alignContent: 'center',
    justifyContent:'center',
    marginRight: '70%'
  }
});
```

With this code, my sample application crashes with the message `AwesomeProject has stopped`.

If I change `<View style={itemStyle.content}>` to `<View style={itemStyle}>`it doesn't crash anymore.

So I'm confused. Why for an `Image` I can use `.content`, but for a `View`, the application crashes if I use `.content`?

EDIT:

Android Monitor shows this: `Abort message: 'availableWidth is indefinite so widthMeasureMode must be YGMeasureModeUndefined'`.

Comment: Did you try it without `StyleSheet.create`? I personally write my styles like so `const styles = { ... }`

Comment: You use `itemStyle.content` on `View`, should be `imageStyle.content`, or you need to create an `itemStyle` object

Comment: @Raymond I changed to that now. The situation is exactly same.

Comment: @LGSon Sorry, I copied a different StyleSheet by accident. I updated my question now.

Comment: What version of RN are you using?

Comment: @Raymond `0.48.4`.

Comment: Aren't you suppose to use `StyleSheet.create()`? ... With `itemStyle` you don't, with `imageStyle` you do and it works, and the docs. says to use it

Comment: @LGSon I am using `StyleSheet.create()`. I switched to `const` just to try what Raymond said, and then I copy pasted that style. I changed it again to what I was using originally. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @LGSon he doesn't have to use `StyleSheet.create`. As long as it is an object RN is happy

Comment: I also tried your source code as is and it works absolutely fine on my device. You probably have an error somewhere else.

Comment: You're right, the error may come from another place. Android Monitor shows this issue: `Abort message: 'availableWidth is indefinite so widthMeasureMode must be YGMeasureModeUndefined`.

Comment: Try removing the `%` from your style values. Use flex instead. `flex: 0.95` will be equivalent to `width: 95%`. To quote the React Native docs "All dimensions in React Native are unitless, and represent density-independent pixels." - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/height-and-width.html

Comment: @Dan I replaced `width` with `flex`. I don't know how to replace `height` though. Anyway, I removed that as well. But the error is still the same.

Comment: Ok, but even if I comment out both the height and the width and don't use them at all, the error remains.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue recently, and struggled a lot with it. 
This issue happens when you give values for margin in '%'. Remove the % values and the issue should resolve